# How do you convert data types in Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm very new to powershell and am running into walls trying to convert a string to a integer.

If I run the following command: Get-DefaultAudioDeviceVolume it often returns a number that looks something like: 50.05816%, which I have confirmed to be a string. I need to convert this to a whole number integer (50). Obviously I could hard code the integer in my script, but for the purpose of the script I need it to be flexible in it's conversion. The result of the previous test changes and I want to pass along the whole integer further down the line.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast it to integer and replace the "%" with nothing:

```
[int]$var = (Get-DefaultAudioDeviceVolume).Replace("%","")
```

Powershell does automatic type casting and starts from the left. So when $var is defined as an integer, it will try to convert the right side to the same type.

Comment: It really is returning the result with the "%". When I try to run the script you suggest I receive the following error:

    Cannot convert value "50.05816%" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Fixed the answer. James C.'s should work just as well.

Answer (score 3):

If the string contains the % symbol you would need to remove this, then you can use the `-as` operator to convert to `[int]`

```
[string]$vol = "50.05816%"

$vol_int = $vol.Replace('%','') -as [int]
```

The `-as` operator is very useful and has many other uses, this article goes through a number of them: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2013/08/13/utilizing-the-as-operator.aspx